# 403 Forbidden Upload with jbimage and Tinymce WYSIWYG Text Editor

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

i'm trying to integrate WYSIWYG text editor: tinymce and photo manager/uploader: jbimage. i work this project on linux ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit).

**The problem**

The upload process from jbimage work 100% on local. but when i upload the script into my server, the upload process with jbimage show 403 access forbidden, i already google about this problem like folder permission, case sensitive, and etc but still none.

here's my code:

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/plugins/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",

plugins: [
  "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
  "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
  "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
],

toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",

relative_urls: false

});
</script>
```

**jbimage config.php**

```
$config['img_path'] = '/myproject/assets/images/upload'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

any help will be so appreciate, thanks

Comment: This is almost always folder permissions. Are you sure your upload folder (and parent folders?) is 777?

Comment: yes of course sir, i'm sure about the folder permission. i'm trying to upload to my another server with same code and work 100%. so it's look like my server is the problem but i don't know what exactly is

Comment: I'm having a similar issue is why I found your question. One of the things to try was turning off php's safe mode. http://serverfault.com/questions/444328/how-can-i-disable-safe-mode-for-php-on-web-server